# Android studio install fail in MacBook Pro 2021

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

Recently got upgraded to new MacBook Pro 14inch and have macOS Monterey 12.0.1 and I can't install android studio to it. SDK cant be dowloaded, showing no SDK found and even cant download new.

[image: SDK missing]

[image]

[image]

Help indeed, new to Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this was solved as I dowloaded the other BETA of android Bumblebee or Chipmunk, they downloaded the SDK and I noted the SDK location then installed the android studio for M1 and located the SDK that was a success.

Hope this might help others too.